# Is there a code to make first JFrame's elements render fast?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

My Swing application runs well, switching between frames happens fastly. But when I run my Java Swing app the first JFrame appears but without elements on it, after 2-3sec, elements show. Is there a solution for this?

```
JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
jframe.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
jframe.add(new JButton("button"));
jframe.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Depends on what your application is doing to initialize those elements: connecting to database, reading files, making REST calls, etc. There is no such property as `jframe.setDrawElementsFast(true);`

Comment: I have edited my Post, check out the code

Comment: If that is all your code then something is wrong with your machine. On my machine everything appears at the same time

Comment: Do you set FookAndFeel? It usually takes some seconds...

Comment: I've tested this code on multiple machines, same result, and there's no FookAndFeel.

Comment: If all else fails, there is flash screen support for a startup animation. It might be that some initialisation takes long. Getting a DB connection, or a complex swing layout with 100s of components.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: This piece of code doesn't reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code slightly since you shouldn't be adding many items to `JFrame` but to a `JPanel`.  I am still uncertain what the problem is.

```java
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class JFrameTest extends JPanel {
   JFrame jframe = new JFrame();

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      // get out of static context and start on EDT
     SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()-> new JFrameTest().start());
   }
   public void start() {
      setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
      jframe.add(this);

      jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      add(new JButton("button"));
      jframe.pack();

      // center on screen.
      jframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      jframe.setVisible(true);
   }

}
```